# Stop Vim wrapping lines in the middle of a word

Tags: vim

After doing `:set wrap`, Vim wraps lines longer than the window.

But is it possible to have Vim wrap to a new line on blank spaces only, not half-way through a word?

Comment: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/soft-wrapping-text/

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`:help wrap`

> This option changes how text is displayed.  It doesn't change the text
>   in the buffer, see 'textwidth' for that.
>   When on, lines longer than the width of the window will wrap and
>   displaying continues on the next line.  When off lines will not wrap
>   and only part of long lines will be displayed.  When the cursor is
>   moved to a part that is not shown, the screen will scroll
>   horizontally.
>   The line will be broken in the middle of a word if necessary.  **See
>   'linebreak' to get the break at a word boundary.**

`:help linebreak`

> If on Vim will wrap long lines at a character in 'breakat' rather
>   than at the last character that fits on the screen.

`:help breakat`

> 'breakat' 'brk' `string` (default `" ^I!@*-+;:,./?"`)

So, `:set linebreak` and it should work out of box. Or you can restrict `breakat` to just break on spaces, instead of spaces+punctuation.

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Answer (score 24):

Use

```
:set linebreak
```

Or `'lbr'` for short. It will break lines on characters included in your `'breakat'` option, which includes a space by default.

Answer (score 4):

With vim open, press esc and enter

`:set lbr`

Answer (score 2):

The following will do a line wrap without breaking any words and preserve the shorter lines.

```
:set formatoptions+=w
:set tw=80
gggqG
```

To try and format the current paragraph try the follwoing:

```
:nnoremap Q gqip
```

Answer (score 1):

The following commands work for me, and I am using Red Hat 7.x at work, and Cygwin 3.1.4 at home.  The exclamation point acts like a not operator.

```
:set wrap
:set wrap!
```